# what is the bounds / size of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer content?

Tags: avfoundation

I have a UIView with two layers in it. One is an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer with videoGravity == AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect. The other is an analysis of the frame data. I would like to base the rect of my analysis layer to fit the content of the preview layer.

Is there an easy way of getting the size of the actual content in the preview layer? It feels like I am missing something as I approach calculating this myself.

I have some screen shots demonstrating the effect but am too new to post them here, will try to get them posted elsewhere if they can help clarify my issue.

Answer (score -2):

Even though it has been several months I still want to answer this in case someone else has the same issue.

It would appear that you could use:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.Contents.Width
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.Contents.Height
```

Although I have had issues getting the proper content from this when capturing video.

Instead I would use:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.Bounds
```

or

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.BorderWidth 
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.BorderHeight
```